# Javascript : Get Parent Node Name

Tags: javascript, text, range, parent

How should I get the Parent nodeName of a text while I'm on it with the cursor?

```
<div id="holder" contentEditable="true">
    Stackoverflow is the <b>coolest</b> Q&A website in the world.
</div>
```

And as a result we have:

- Stackoverflow is the **coolest** Q&A
  website in the world.

So if the cursor is on the `coolest` I would like to get it's parent nodeName which is `b`

Please no libraries, just pure javascript.

Comment: Are you okay with a jQuery solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.getElementById('holder').addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
        somevar = e.target.nodeName;
    }, false);
} else {
    document.getElementById('holder').attachEvent('onmouseover', function (e) {
        somevar = e.srcElement.nodeName;
    });
}
```

EDIT: updated code and example in accordance with question edit and comments.

[**See example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/sPmHh/2/)

Comment: Nice to know, that IE understands event as a handler function param. I always thought, that `window.event` is the only way to get event object. +1

Comment: @CIRK: change `click` & `onclick` with `mouseover` & `onmouseover`, and change `.tagName` to `.nodeName` and the above should give you what you ask for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="holder" contentEditable="true">
   Stackoverflow is the <b onclick="alert(this.tagName)">coolest</b> Q&A website in the world.
</div>
```